# Laravel Flysystem sftp Permission Denied

Tags: php, laravel-5, ssh, flysystem

Im trying to use the *Laravel Flysystem* with the sftp adaptor from PHP League (league/flysystem-sftp). Using Laravel 5.4 and version 3.7 of the Flysystem.

When I attempt to *put* a file on the server, i get the message:

***Cannot connect to someadress.com:22. Error 13. Permission denied***

Here is the code:

```
$box = new Filesystem(new SftpAdapter(Config::get('flysystem.connections.sftp')));
$box->put('test.txt', 'bar');
```

and the connection details from the config:

```
'sftp' => [
     'driver'     => 'sftp',
     'host'       => 'someadress.com',
     'port'       => 22,
     'username'   => 'someuser',
     'password'   => 'ArndomPa55',
     'privateKey' => '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa',
     'root'       => '/var/www/html/site/box/',
     'timeout'    => 20,
 ],
```

When I make an SSH connection from the server where this is running, it connects fine, without a password prompt, so it is using the Private Key. So not sure why this isn't working.

I've checked the *secure* log on the receiving server and nothing is in there.

Comment: Now that is a good MCVE. Did you resolve the issue? This problem occurs when the local user that the application runs under doesn't have permission to read */home/user/.ssh/id_rsa*.  It works from the command line because your user *does* have permission to read that key.

Comment: Also, you're specifying a `'password'` option along with `'privateKey'`, which won't work if the password *is not the private key passphrase*. When the two are used together, the value of `'password'` must be the passphrase for the private key, not the password of the remote user.

Comment: @CyRossignol I got this working in the end, I did remove password, but it turned out to be an issue with apache being the user attempting to connect, as such I needed to give it access and have the keys in a place it had permission to access.

Comment: Great! Sorry I didn't see this question sooner :) Are you going to post this as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 4):

While extremely old, and I am committing necromancy here, I came across this issue and none of these fixes helped.  What happened (and may happen to others) is that the key type was openssh not rsa and the call to `ssh2::_privatekey_login` returned false, causing the whole event to fail. If your key is openssh (identified by `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` as the header), run the following to convert it to RSA, fixing the problem.

`ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f [filename here]`

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I tried to figure this out for hours and this finally worked.

Comment: yeap RSA problem, checked source code and didnt want to believe first, then tested everything and only this one worked

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem. 
The exception was :

```
local.ERROR: LogicException: Could not login with username: username, host: xx.xx.xx.xx.
```

Following code in vendor\league\flysystem-sftp\src\SftpAdapter i found that hostFingerprint always returned null. 
After that I just removed `privateKey => 'path/to/key'` from the configuration for example

```
'sftp' => [
     'driver'     => 'sftp',
     'host'       => 'someadress.com',
     'port'       => 22,
     'username'   => 'someuser',
     'password'   => 'ArndomPa55',
     //'privateKey' => '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa',
     'root'       => '/var/www/html/site/box/',
     'timeout'    => 20,
 ]
```

, and i connected to the server. I think it has to do something with the servers sftp configuration. For now that suites me for testing my scripts but i will look for the reason.

I hope that helps finding a permanent solution.

Comment: I had this at another stage on another server and got it solved, but was a different problem  to the one above.
the one above was that Apache was making the call, and as such didn't have a key to connect to the server. Solved that using other answers on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I have changed the user actually do php execution to the user writed sftp configuration. It was working on php-fpm. I have changed user & group on php-pfm confguration. I have not changed http.conf It works!

Answer (score 0):

For me the error above was due to wrong ownership of private key file

I did chmod the key to 600 and set ownership set to
`www-data:www-data`

changed to the following and could authenticate fine
`actualuser:www-data`